# One to many relationship needs all of the many records to match a condition

Tags: sql

I've got a one-to-many relationship with these two tables:

```
p2c {
    parent_id,
    child_id
}

child {
    child_id, -- pk
    count1,
    count2
}
```

If I do this:

```
select distinct parent_id from p2c 
join child on p2c.child_id = child.child_id
where count1 = count2
```

I get the parents where one of the children have the counts equal. How do I get the parent where ALL of its children have the counts equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY/HAVING as follows:

```
select  parent_id 
from    p2c 
        join child on p2c.child_id = child.child_id
group by parent_id
having count(case when count1 = count2 then 1 end) = count(*);
```

This basically counts rows where `count1 = count2` and only returns `parent_id`s where this count is the same as the total

Comment: You know, after all these years of writing SQL, I didn't know you could do a comparison within a HAVING clause. Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived table first , to get the count of rows and rows where they match:

```
  select
    *
    from
    pc2
    join
    (
    select
    child_id,
    count1,
    count2,
    count(child_id) as NUM_ROWS,
    count(case when count1 = count2 then 1 else null) as NUM_MATCHES
    from child
    group by child_Id
    ) child
    on pc2.child_id = child.child_id
    where child.num_rows = num_matches
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing that you mixed up child and parent. A child should refer to it's parent, not the other way around.

Comment: That is what the actual DB structure looks like. Actually, table p2c implements a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you should look up what "parent" and "child" mean and while you're at it, look into how you implement a many-to-many relationship in a relational DB, because this isn't it.